# Waiting for a thread to finish in c# / Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin

I got a tricky thing here. I am developing an iOS App with Xamarin at the moment. (I think if you don't know about xamarin but c# you might know the answer as well - its an issue with threading basically!) I have a table with several entries, and when the user clicks one of the entries, it is required that i load data from a web service. This data is then displayed in the second table shown another view i push to. The problem is: In the exact moment the user clicks the table entry, the push segue to another view is triggered, the viewDidLoad() there is also triggered, in which i set the tables entries. But now sometimes it occurs that the async networking task from the previous view didn't finish, which leaves the table empty. To sum it up: I need to trigger a Table.Reload() on the View i push to, after the asynchronous networking request has done its work. How do i do that? I am really stuck here. Here are some details of my Code:

**First View Controller**

```
    public async override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        //Sends the titles, subtitles, and the Headline to the DetailView
        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);
        ...
        Task<String[,]> getJsonDataTask = SearchRequest.searchRequest (text, "Calendar");
        arrayContent = await getJsonDataTask;
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            tableItems.Add(arrayContent [1, i]);
            tableSubtitles.Add(  arrayContent [5,i]);

            Dates.Add(tableItems[i]);
            Descriptions.Add (tableSubtitles [i]);

        }
        var calendarDetailController = segue.DestinationViewController as CalendarDetailVController;


        if (calendarDetailController != null) {
            Console.WriteLine ("preparesegue"+Dates.Count);
            calendarDetailController.Dates = Dates;
            calendarDetailController.Descriptions = Descriptions;
            calendarDetailController.TableTitle = text;
            calendarDetailController.id = id;
        }
```

So here i am starting an async Thread (it needs to by ansync. cause its a network request)
And i am transferring the data to the view controller i push to.
In the

**Secound View Controller**

I just fetch the given data like

```
    public List<String> Dates { get; set; }
    public CalendarViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Dates = new List<String> ();
    }
```

And then i reload the tables data in ViewDidLoad();

```
        public override async void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
        //as the resource loading is async. whe need to refresh table here


        TableView.ReloadData ();

     }
```

Sometimes, if this ViewDidLoad() gets triggered, AFTER the async task finished, this works. But i need to trigger the Reload when the Data has fully arrived. Do you understand my problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you start it async if you need to wait for its finish?

Comment: because it is a networking request - it needs to run in a separate task - or doesn't it?

Comment: well if it doesn't need to i could solve it like this - i don't want to though because i also use the networking request function in an android app-and this will give me a NetworkOnMainThreadException there.

Comment: also an async method makes the app more fluent - the push animation is still smooth and doesn't freeze while doing the task

Comment: I don't know if there's a good way to wait on a separate method to finish. Could the data be loaded from the ViewDidAppear method?

Comment: not really because the searchquery for the webrequest depends on which row the user clicked ..

Comment: but i think thats a good idea.. i can try to set it up like you said

Comment: yeah that works -cool i didn't think of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you pass your task instead of the result of the task?

Change:

```
public List<String> Dates { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public Task<String[,]> DatesTask{get;set;}
```

And you execute the task in the viewDidAppaer of your second viewcontroller:

```
    public override async void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
                //as the resource loading is async. whe need to refresh table here

Task.Run (async delegate {
                await DatesTask().ContinueWith(() => {
                   InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {  
                            TableView.ReloadData ();
                          });
                });
            });


     }
```

I would not recommend to make a method like ViewDidAppaer wait, instead i would let a task handle the execution of your method, and once it is done, make your tableview refresh. That way you will not freeze your userinterface while executing your task!

Or if you really want to execute your task in your first viewcontroller, you should execute your task BEFORE performing `PrepareForSegue` .

Comment: Thank you! This is a very detailed Solution And it works well !

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly it seems that you only need to pass the async `Task` from the view that initiated the call to your second view that needs to `await` it to finish, nothing fancy here.